# Dynamic form builder using KO

Tags: reactjs, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a dynamic form builder. A user can specify how many textboxes they want per row. Let's say I specified that my form must have 2 textboxes per row then I'd expect the following to be rendered:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <input class="form-control" type="color" value="#563d7c" id="example-color-input">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <input class="form-control" type="color" value="#563d7c" id="example-color-input">
  </div>
</div>
```

In my .jsx file I recieve a JSON which contains 4 names, using this I'd like to iterate through and create 4 textboxes having 2 per row.

```
  static buildForm(fields, isSingleColumn) {
    let questions = fields().length;

    return (
        <form ref="form" data-bind="foreach: fields">
            <div class="row">

            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
```

I was hoping to have an int outside of the return within buildForm to increment everytime it creates a textbox and then if it's reached its last one i.e 2nd textbox then close the div row, however I'm not sure how to do this as im using data-bind.

Is this the correct way of doing this or is their better approaches/solutions?

Comment: Why oh why are you mixing React and Knockout code?

Comment: I wouldn't mix knockout and react, that's just an unnecessary headache. Either knockout templates will do the job or in react, set the number as state and loop the output

Answer (score 0):

Instead of any nth-textbox hacks in your markup to determine the row's end I would split them up into separate arrays in the view-model first. Then you can simply use a nested foreach binding to mirror the structure of your model:

```js
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.fields = ko.observableArray(["field 1", "field 2", "field 3", "field 4", "field 5"]);
  self.chunkSize = ko.observable(2);

  self.itemChunks = ko.computed(function() {
    var chunks = [];
    var items = self.fields().slice(); //shallow copy
    while (self.chunkSize() && items.length > self.chunkSize()) {
      var chunk = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < self.chunkSize(); i++) chunk.push(items.shift());
      chunks.push(chunk);
    }
    chunks.push(items); //add any remaining
    return chunks;
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px dotted silver;
  padding: 2px;
}

.col-6 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

chunk size (fields per row)<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: chunkSize" />
<br/>
<form ref="form" data-bind="foreach: itemChunks">
  <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <div class="col-6">
      <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: $data" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use templates instead.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: formFields">
    <div class="col-6">
    <input class="form-control" type="color" value="#563d7c" id="example-color-input">
  </div>
</div>
```

in your Object modal based on input populate formFields.